# Google cloud backend-service for HTTP load balancing ignores custom ports

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have an app running on port 31280 exposed via nodePorts from a Kubernetes cluster. Same port is exposed through named-port on the instance group used by cluster for load balancing. While creating a backend-service with HTTP protocol, the service is created at default http port(80) even if I specify custom named-port.

Exposed named-port for instance group is:

```
gcloud preview instance-groups --zone='asia-east1-a' list-services gke-dropwizard-service-31ccc162-group

[
  {
    "endpoints": [
      {
        "name": "dropwizard-example-service-http",
        "port": 31280
      }
    ],
    "fingerprint": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
]
```

Health check is:

```
gcloud compute http-health-checks describe dropwizard-example-service

checkIntervalSec: 5
creationTimestamp: '2015-08-11T12:08:16.245-07:00'
description: Dropwizard Example Sevice health check ping
healthyThreshold: 2
host: ''
id: 'XXXXXXX'
kind: compute#httpHealthCheck
name: dropwizard-example-service
port: 31318
requestPath: /ping
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/httpHealthChecks/dropwizard-example-service
timeoutSec: 3
unhealthyThreshold: 2
```

Health port(31318) is also exposed via named port in instance group.

Commands used to create backend-service is:

```
gcloud compute backend-services create "dropwizard-example-external-service" --description "Dropwizard Example Service via Nodeports from Kubernetes cluster" --http-health-check "dropwizard-example-service" --port-name "dropwizard-example-service-http" --timeout "30"
```

Command used to add instance group to backend-service is:

```
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend "dropwizard-example-external-service" --group "gke-dropwizard-service-31ccc162-group" --zone "asia-east1-a" --balancing-mode "UTILIZATION" --capacity-scaler "1" --max-utilization "0.8"
```

Finally created backend-service is described as:

```
gcloud compute backend-services describe dropwizard-example-external-service

backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  description: ''
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/resourceviews/v1beta2/projects/XXX/zones/asia-east1-a/resourceViews/gke-dropwizard-service-31ccc162-group
  maxUtilization: 0.8
creationTimestamp: '2015-08-11T13:10:46.608-07:00'
description: Dropwizard Example Service via Nodeport from Kubernetes cluster
fingerprint: XXXXXXXXXXXX
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/httpHealthChecks/dropwizard-example-service
id: 'XXXX'
kind: compute#backendService
name: dropwizard-example-external-service
port: 80
portName: dropwizard-example-service-http
protocol: HTTP
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXX/global/backendServices/dropwizard-example-external-service
timeoutSec: 30
```

I don't understand which part is wrong. Why backend-service is using port 80?

Comment: I've also had problems since earlier today.. :S for some reason the backend doesn't have access to the nodes.. :/

Comment: Thank you for bring this to our attention I have reported this issue to our engineering team. You can get updates on this link (https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=234&thanks=234&ts=1439582902). You can subscribe to this issue by clicking on the star at the top left on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was wrong.  It does seem to work.  I had a typo in my script.

My script is here - I literally just ran this and it worked properly.

https://gist.github.com/thockin/36fea15cc0deb08a768a

Original response for posterity:

I'm not an expert in the GCE L7 API yet, but I *have* made it work in Kubernetes.  I think there's a bug in the --port-name logic.  If you specify --port directly it seems to work for me.  I'm filing an issue internally.